# Why IRQF_SAMPLE_RANDOM flag has been removed?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

As far as I know, IRQF_SAMPLE_RANDOM flag has been introduced to allow some interrupts to add randomness that used to generate random number in the Linux kernel.

However, the current version of the Linux doesn't utilize the IRQF_SAMPLE_RANDOM  flag and automatically updates randomness regardless of the interrupt number, which means for every interrupt, it adds some entropy to the randomness.

However, it might be utilized by the malicious attack who have perfect control on the devices and interrupts can undermine the randomness. Why the flag has been removed? Was it proved that it is almost impossible to affect the randomness by controlling the interrupts?

Comment: Have you read commit messages on the subject? What did they tell?

Comment: It seems that add_interrupt_randomness which was invoked only when the flag has been set is invoked after every interrupt handling in current Linux kernel; however, it seems that all the interrupt event cannot have an effect on the randomness, which means only one amongst the several interrupts ensued during a specific interval can have influence on randomness. However, it seems that this decision was made not because of considering the security but because of performance.

Comment: And to answer your question, I have read the commit messages. Is there something that I couldn't catch from the messages? If there is an old discussion page related to this issue, could you let me know?